# nuget creating two package folders?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

OK,

So i recently reinstalled windows 10 and upgraded vs2013 -> vs2015. At this point i tried to grab a couple of nuget packages.

The problem i am having is that i have a .nuget/packages folder at the same level as my solution file (set via NuGet.config) but i also have exactly the same folder getting created in the root of my user folder.

the packages folder for my solution contains the packages installed for that solution, while the one i don't want in my user directory contains all the packages for all the projects and solutions i am working on.

Is there a way i can prevent this .nuget folder being created in my user directory? it seems useless when i already have package folders for my solutions

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can clear the `.nuget\packages` directory under your user profile however the packages will be downloaded again if you install them again.

### Package retrieval

`%USERPROFILE%\.nuget\packages` is the local machine cache used by NuGet v3 when installing NuGet packages for new project types, such as Universal Windows projects.

For a C# console project NuGet will use the `%LOCALAPPDATA%\NuGet\Cache` directory which is also what NuGet v2 uses.

ASP.NET Core projects currently use their own `%USERPROFILE%\.dnx\packages` directory for NuGet packages.

### Specifying a custom NuGet package location

To prevent NuGet from copying the packages to your user profile you can create a new `%NUGET_PACKAGES%` environment variable pointing to the location where you want NuGet to copy the files e.g. `C:\git-repositories\.nuget\packages`.

To prevent NuGet from copy the packages to the solution folder too you can create a new `NuGet.config` file either in the solution folder or at any higher level up to the root. As content you can specify following XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <config>
    <add key="repositoryPath" value="C:\git-repositories\.nuget\packages" />
  </config>
</configuration>
```

As help for configuration inheritance please follow this link: [NuGet Configuration Inheritance](http://docs.myget.org/docs/how-to/nuget-configuration-inheritance)

Comment: is there not possibility to prevent nuget from copying the packages to `.nuget\packages` under my user profile?

Comment: For NuGet v2 you can specify a NuGetCachePath environment variable which defines the global packages path. For NuGet v3 the environment variable is NUGET_PACKAGES

Comment: Thanks, I have modified your answer adding the section about overriding the custom package location.

Comment: %NUGET_PACKAGES% is it still the correct name? here in the link https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior it says that it should be %PACKAGEHOME%.

Comment: That page says the repository path can be defined as any environment variable. What this means is that the variable will be expanded. Previously the NuGet.Config file could only have a directory path. PACKAGEHOME is not a known environment variable that NuGet uses. It still uses [NUGET_PACKAGES](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/4cccb13833ad29d6a0bcff055460d964f1b49cfe/src/NuGet.Core/NuGet.Configuration/Utility/SettingsUtility.cs#L17)

Comment: @MattWard sorry I am not good with this environment parameters. Should we define it as "variable name=repositoryPath" and "variable value= %NUGET_PACKAGES%\C:\git-repositories\.nuget\packages"

Comment: The environment name is NUGET_PACKAGES and the value for you will be C:\git-repositories\.nuget\packages

Comment: @MattWard I do not have any of the package locations that you mention. I have a %USERPROFILE%\.nuget\packages, not %APPDATA%\.nuget\packages.
I have a %USERPROFILE%\.dnx\packages, not %APPDATA%\.dnx\packages. I have a %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache, not %APPDATA%\Local\NuGet\Cache (which would be in AppData\Roaming). I have Windows 10 + VS2015.

Comment: @JohnPankowicz - You are correct. I have fixed the paths.