# Visual Studio 2015 does not respect nuget's repository path for ASP.NET Core projects

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, nuget, asp.net-core-mvc, nuget-package

I have Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise with Update3. In one VS solution i have 3 different projects. 2 projects are `ASP.Net Core` and 3rd project is classic `.Net 4.6.2`

All 3 projects have nuget packages and i want to store them at one location relative to solution file. `(eg C:Root\Lib\packages)` Certain packages will shared between 2 `ASP.Net Core` projects. However note that i am **NOT** trying to share a package between `ASP.Net Core` projects and classing `.net 4.6.2` project.

So i put `nugget.config` file as shown below at the `C:\root`.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <configuration>
    <config>
        <add key="repositoryPath" value=".\Lib\packages" />
    </config>  
  </configuration>
```

The above settings stores the nugget packages for `.Net 4.6.2` project into `C:\Root\Lib\packages\` folder. Exactly where i wanted.

However the `ASP.NET Core` projects does not respect repositoryPath. I found discussion [here](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/626)  that says

> project.json project doesn't support repositoryPath config now, if you
>   want to change packages default location, you can set "NUGET_PACKAGES"
>   environment variable to do that.

So on both the `ASP.NET Core` projects i added **NUGET_PACKAGES** environment variable and set the value to `.\Lib\packages` and clicked on restore  packages. However that still restores `ASP.NEt Core` packages to **C:\Users{user-name}\ .nuget\packages**

**Update1**
I set environment variable in `ASP.NET Core` project's property page.
Right Click on Project ->Properties->Debug->Add

[image]

**Update2**

so based on the suggestions below I added `NUGET_PACKAGES` environment variable via windows at user level. and sets its value to `C:\Root\Lib\packages` folder. and also deleted `'nuget.config` file from `C:\root`
I noticed only `asp.net core` projects which has `package.json` file honors the environment variable. The `classic .Net 4.6.2` project restore packages to their default location, it does not honor `NUGET_PACKAGES` variable.

**2nd approach I tried**
Also as per the documentation [here](http://docs.nuget.org/consume/nuget-config-file) under `Environment variables in configuration` section, we can now use environment variable in `nuget.config` file. I am not able to get this working for any project.
 1. I removed `NUGET_PACKAGES` environment variable from windows.
 2. Add new variable 'MyPath' with value `C:\Root`
 3. Add `nuget.config` file at `c:\Root`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <configuration>
    <config>
        <add key="repositoryPath" value="%MyPath%\Lib\packages" />
    </config>  
</configuration>
```

Doing so `asp.net core` projects restored the package to **C:\Users{user-name}\ .nuget\packages** that is not what i have configured.
While `classic .net 4.6.2` project gives error `The given path format is not supported`

Comment: @LP12， if you have an existing packages folder under your solution root, please delete it before NuGet will place packages in the new location, and then check it again. Is your Nuget 3.4 x version? Do you mean that you add the environment variables in the Nuget.confi file? http://docs.nuget.org/consume/nuget-config-file

Comment: @JackZhai I'm using Nuget version 3.5.0.1484 ( VS 2015 Update 3). I added Environment variable by right clicking on project ->properties->debug->add environment variable. ( see update 1 above)

Comment: Environment variables added via the project properties are only available at runtime. You need the environment variable available at the time the NuGet packages are restored, prior to building the project. So add the environment variable via Windows, not Visual Studio. You'll probably need to restart Visual Studio before it's picked up.

Comment: If I add the environment variable at machine level wouldn't that affect all the projects on that machine? including `classing .net` projects as well as `.net core projects`

Comment: Also with environment variable approach all the developers on the team have to add this environment variable on their machine. Does not make sense. With nuget.config file approach, we had source controlled the nuget.config file and that approached worked for all developers.

Comment: please see update2

Comment: @LP13, It is the system environment variable which sets a global packages path: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35710866/can-the-dnx-dotnetcore-package-cache-location-be-changed. In addition, the path /.nuget\packages should be a local machine cache: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35283331/nuget-creating-two-package-folders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use "NUGET_PACKAGES" variable to config the repository path for Asp.Net Core project and also place a Nuget.Config file in the root folder to control the repository path for classic .Net project. It works at my side.

The only issue is that all the developers need to add this environment variable just as you mentioned to achieve this. There isn't any way to avoid this for now as I know. However, if your team members don't want to change the location of the packages for Asp.Net Core project, then they don't need to add this environment variable. The packages will be restored to the default path on their machine and the .Net Core project could find and use them automatically.